# What's a good way to insert a resource id into the params of another resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm really new to programming, so I'm having trouble explaining this -- please forgive.

I have a Document model and a Note model in my rails app.  A note belongs to a document, and a document has many notes -- the foreign key in the notes table is document_id.

On my document show page, I have a form for a note which uses a :content attribute as a text_area field.

What I'd like to do is pass the document's id into the note params so the note would have both the :content the user submits alng with the :document_id based on the document_path.

Currently I'm adding the :document_id into the note's params hash using a hidden_field form helper, and sending the whole thing to the NotesController, but I hope there's a cleaner / perhaps easier way.

If this makes sense, can someone suggest a better way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes have something like

```
resources :documents do
  resources :notes
end
```

Then you should be adding a note via this route

/documents/5/notes/new

Then in your NotesController have

```
def create
  @document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
  @note = @document.notes.build(params[:note])
  if @note.save
    # Blah
  else
    # Blah
  end
end
```

(In no way has this been tested - but it gives you an idea of how to do it in a RESTFUL style without hidden fields)

Comment: Will this work even if the note form is on the document show page?  I tried nesting routes like this, but wasnt able to pull up the documents show page.

Comment: Yep. Because the document show page will still have the ID. Access the document via /document/3 and your form path for a NEW note would have to look like <% form_for @Note.new, :url => new_document_note_path(@document) do |f| %>

Comment: This does work, but I'm still uneasy about it.  For one, this seems to create thicker controllers than expected.  After all, it's just a params value for document_id, to go through so much in the controller just to pass that value doesn't seem very "Rails" (aka supposedly elegant).  Also, I've simplified my question to get a better handle on it.  In reality, I am also trying to pass in a user_id (since notes belong to users as well as documents).  Are hidden fields bad?  Is using the nested routes approach the common alternative?